# Выбор оптимальной ФС для установки ОС GNU/Linux на SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, ext4

Какую **ФС** выбрать для установки ОС **GNU/Linux** на **SSD**?
Я нагуглил 3 варианта.

1. F2FS
2. EXT4 с отключённым журналом
3. EXT4 (по умолчанию с включённым журналом)

Я больше склоняюсь к **F2FS**, но из-за того. что в этой ФС не поддерживается определение версии, в некоторый дистрибутивах, например в моём **openSUSE Tumleweed**, F2FS по умолчанию в чёрном списке, причём даже флешку не увидит если из списка не убрать, а при обновлении, возможно, может перезаписать чёрный список. Не очень понимаю почему так, буду рад если подробно объясните, а также расскажите другие недостатки F2FS.

Также советуют возможно по ранее указанной причине, а возможно и нет, использовать **EXT4** с отключенным журналом. Есть ли тут какие-то приимущества перед F2FS.

Но к сожалению. нагуглил на хабре и [такое](https://habr.com/ru/company/kingston_technology/blog/539532/). К этот статье отнёсся как вбросу со стороны Кингстон и не воспринял её всерьёз, но может я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Почему бы не рассмотреть btrfs? Там довольно хорошая оптимизация под SSD, да и место сжимает автоматически через zstd сжатие.

Comment: Так же как вариант, рассмотрите ZFS.

Comment: Основная фишка ZFS/BtrFS это версионность и снапшоты, как в git-е. Мне они в моей ФС не нужны, и накладные расходы на это тоже. По этому EXT4 для HDD в не конкуренции, она надёжнее лучше и быстрее, и в отличие от XFS гибче, например позволяет отключать журнал. ZFS/BtrFS без жёсткой необходимости версиионности и снапшотов - это не серьёзно, а оптимизация под SSD есть у каждой актуальной FS!

Comment: вы сами ответили на свой вопрос `Выбор оптимальной ФС для ... SSD` далее `оптимизация под SSD есть у каждой актуальной FS`. Если у вас не какой нибудь высоко нагруженный сервер, а простой домашний/рабочий комп то за глаза хватит и ext4, зачем отключать журнал непонятно, это экономия на спичках, единственно что можно это подкрутить параметры, у себя остановился на таких `rw,noatime,commit=60`

Comment: Живу с обычным ext4 с обычным журналом и никаких проблем не имею, зачем мудрить

Answer (score 4):

Я бы хотел сослаться [на опыт Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization).

Первый ключевой момент:

> Use the ext4 filesystem (the most mature filesystem) unless you have reason not to.

Если у вас нет особых задач и специфики - используйте обычный проверенный временем ext4.

Второй ключевой момент:

> Some firmware versions on some SSD models have bugs that result in data corruption when used in certain ways.
>
> In particular, many drives, including Samsung, Micron, Crucial have problems with discard/TRIM

Думаете, хотя бы ведущие разработчики SSD корректно реализуют команды протокола, добавленные в протокол именно для облегчения работы SSD? Да вот нет. Потому опция монтирования discard и остаётся отключенной по-умолчанию. От наиболее известных/проблемных моделей прикрывает само ядро, а сколько остаются неизвестными? У меня, например, вовсе не хватит познаний на диагностику, в какой же именно ситуации SSD повреждает данные чтобы предложить добавить эту модель в список blacklist в ядре linux. Повреждает данные - значит неисправен и заменяется на другой.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, ознакомлюсь на днях.
Но я так и не услышал чем же плоха F2FS и чем же лучше EXT4 кроме того что она проверена на HDD, так что ответ засчитать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Дома уже несколько лет на нескольких компьютерах живёт btrfs. Держит по 4-7 ssd в своём родном raid0. Полёт нормальный.

Из плюсов: недавно один из компов переводил с древних hdd на новые ssd. Просто удалял из btrfs диск, подключал новый, добавлял в btrfs. В конце балансировку запустил и всё работает теперь на новых ssd.

Из минусов: загрузиться с root на btrfs не выйдет (я правда особо и не искал как). Решил через подключение в мать через переходник пары флешек для /boot, объединил их в softraid, следом genkernel->initramfs и дальше уже стандартными путями